# Complement of image of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ is an infinite field, and $f\in F[x]$, such that $F\backslash f(F)$ is finite. What are the possible cardinality of $F\backslash f(F)$?

Assume that $F\subset\overline{K}$ where $K=\mathbb{F}_{p}$ or $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

I'm not even sure how to start.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6820/can-a-non-surjective-polynomial-map-from-an-infinite-field-to-itself-miss-only-f

Comment: According to this MO question (Which is the same question), the problem is not solved in full generality, but it is solved for the most fields, that will occur 'in pratice'. Do you have any restrictions for $F$?

Comment: @MooS: wow thanks a lot, I could not imagine such a simple question would end up on the other site. I don't know any restrictions, but I suppose I can add some...